# Apache Flink sinking its results into OpenSearch

Tags: apache-flink, opensearch

I am running Apache Flink v1.14 on the server which does some pre-processing on the data that is reads from Kafka. I need it to write the results to OpenSearch after which I can fetch the results from OpenSearch.

However, when going through the list of flink v1.14 connectors, I don't see OpenSearch. Is there any other way I can implement it?

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/connectors/datastream/overview/

In the above link, I see only ElasticSearch, no OpenSearch

Answer (score 0):

I think the OpenSearch sink has been added in Flink [1.16](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/connectors/datastream/overview/), so You may consider updating Your cluster. Otherwise, You may need to port the changes to 1.14 (which shouldn't be hard at all) and push as a custom library.

Comment: The OpenSearch connector is not bundled with the Flink release itself, but has a separate release process. The first version that has been released is indeed compatible with Flink 1.16

Comment: @MartijnVisser From your comment, would that mean the only solution here would be to upgrade Flink to 1.16 or later? 
I am in a similar situation, where I have Flink 1.13 and have OpenSearch 2.x on my system. Since I cannot upgrade Flink for development purposes, I am trying to find a way to workaround this. Though silly, I had considered using ElasticSearch connector for Flink to Opensearch just to test but looking into the connector code doesn't seem like that can be possible.

Comment: That is correct indeed. You can try to run it, but most likely the interfaces that this connector uses are either outdated or not existing in Flink 1.14. Keep in mind that both Flink 1.14 and 1.16 are already not supported in the Flink community anymore.